# Find XML sibling in poorly formatted XML with XPath

Tags: xml, rest, xpath

I have some XML returned from a REST interface that I am trying to parse with XPath and example of which is:

```
            <parameter>
                <name>employee first name</name>
                <value>TestF</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <name>employee id</name>
                <value>3345</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <name>date of commencement</name>
                <value>02 Oct 2015, 10:52:00</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <name>employee surname</name>
                <value>TestL</value>
            </parameter>
```

I'm struggling because all of the nodes are named identically, in pairs of     `<name`> `<value`>.

What I'm trying to do is find a `<Parameter`> node that has a specific `<name`> node and return the `<value`> node of that parameter, I hope that makes sense!

What I thought would work is find the correct `<name`> node, then just use the 'following-sibling' function to grab the value but I simply cannot get it to work.

What I have ended up with is:

```
//parameter/name[text()[contains(.,'team')]]/following-sibling::value
```

I've also tried value[1] at the end along with many combinations!

Where I can substitute 'team' with whatever thing I'm looking for, example 'employee id'.

Comment: You handled the contains slightly off. Simply put text() where the period rests: `//parameter/name[contains(text(),'team')]/following-sibling::value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter `parameter` by `name` child element content and then return the corresponding child `value` like so :

```
//parameter[contains(name,'team')]/value
```

Comment: You are a saint. This was exactly what I needed.